# Different delay for multiple nivo slider on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, nivo-slider

I found Nivo slider pretty promising and I have implemented it in several of my new projects.
However, now, I would like to have multiple (2 to 3) sliders on the same page. This is possible. But I want each of them start after a certain delay with respect to last one. Example, first one loads on page load, second one, 1 second after that and so on. I referred to the community support and found this article.
http://dev7studios.com/support/#/discussion/212
However, even this does not solve it.
Please help me with the same. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#slider1').nivoSlider()
    .delay(1000)
    .queue(function(){
        $('#slider2').nivoSlider()
            .delay(1000)
            .queue(function(){
                $('#slider3').nivoSlider();
            });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LfkkF/17/

Comment: Your example doesn't work any more since resources from source page has been removed. Do you know how to make it work with the new version?

Comment: I've replaced external resources with CDN and GitHub based ones

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the above answer to work so i implemented a javascript delay like so:

```
    $(window).load(function() {

setTimeout(function() {$('#slider3').nivoSlider({
   directionNav : false,
   controlNav: false,
  });},250);

});
```

With the number (250) being the delay in miliseconds. I only wanted a very short delay so this method worked for me, but the image displays a loading-icon for the duration of the delay, so anything longer than .5 sec would look ugly I guess.

Here's where I found the method.
http://www.sean.co.uk/a/webdesign/javascriptdelay.shtm